# Angular subscribe with processing error

Tags: angular, http, dictionary, subscribe

Now I am trying to Angular2 Http process.

I know as below function:

```
sendGet(url) {
  return this._http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json());
}

test(url) {
  this.sendGet(url)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        processing data...
      },
      error => {
        processing error...
      },
      () => {
        other...
      }
    );
}
```

But I have used many test() function without "error => ..." as below

```
sendGet(url) {
  return this._http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json());
}

test(url) {
  this.sendGet(url)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        processing data...
      }
    );
}
```

Now I have to process errors all of http get process.

And I think adding 'error => ...' into every test() function is not good method.

I hope there are maybe good method for processing all of http 'error' by only one correction in sendGet() function, but I don't know.

Please let me know how can I do?

Comment: You could convert your Observable to a Promise and then `.catch()` to catch all errors, however you would have chain `.catch()` for all instances of test(). Since the Observable does nothing until you subscribe, the only chance you have to catch any incoming error is in function error handler you pass to `.subscribe()` itself, so I don't think there is a way to manage the errors inside `sendGet()`.

Comment: There is currently no way other than wrapping the Http service into your own service. But the next version of Angular (which is in RC right now) will have a brand new HttpClient service, which is easier to test, easier to use, and provide support for Http interceptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
sendGet(url) {
  return this._http.get(url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch( //error handling );
}
```

With this, if there is an error , it will stop execution there itself instead going to test methods

Comment: This is working well for now. And it needs to return Observable to process in test() function. Is there any possibillity to return nothing to process?

Comment: You can return `Observable.empty()`

Comment: Observable.empty() has some problem. --- ERROR in D:/Work/Project/FrontEnd/src/app/admin/admin-main/admin-main-search/admin-main-search.component.ts (289,47): Property 'json' does not exist on type '{} | Response'.
  Property 'json' does not exist on type '{}'. ---    I think this shows that it is returning something to process yet.

Comment: Can you put your code so that I can check why its failing

Comment: Thanks @Skeptor. That's my mistake. I fixed it myself. And now I have one question. What is difference between "return Observable.empty();" and "return;". I have ever used both of them. It seems they are all works fine. Please let me know!

Comment: `empty` is reactive way of saying the same. You can do something like this `return val? Observable.of(val) : Observable.empty()` . Its a good candidate for a question actually

Answer (score 0):

You can write wrapper service for angular2 http service. Wrapper service can handle errors for all http requests using common code. This wrapper service can also be use to add common request headers  like authentication header before making any http request to server.
Your complete application should use wrapper service to communicate with the server.

Another option will be to use http interceptors to handle error response.